VSTO Outlook: handle when new account added
I'm trying to detect when a new account or store is added in Outlook using VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office), but I'm encountering issues with event triggering. Here's what I've implemented in the ThisAddin_Startup method:
Outlook.NameSpace ns = Application.Session;
Outlook.Stores stores = ns.Stores;
stores.StoreAdd += Stores_StoreAdd;

and the method event:
private void Stores_StoreAdd(Outlook.Store Store)
{
   // some actions here
}

However, the StoreAdd event doesn't seem to fire reliably when a new store (account) is added. I've also tried subscribing to the FolderAdd event on ns.Folders, thinking it might indirectly capture new account additions:
Outlook.Folders folders = ns.Folders;
folders.FolderAdd += Folders_FolderAdd;

private void Folders_FolderAdd(Outlook.MAPIFolder folder)
{
   // some actions here
}

Unfortunately, this approach also doesn't trigger the event when a new account is added. I've tested this with Exchange account types only, but with the same result.
Finally I tried storing the initial number of stores when Outlook starts within the ThisAddin_Startup and then start doing polling with an asynchronous task to:
Application.Session.Stores.Count

and compare this value with the previous one initially set. In case of they are different then I update the previous counter with the current one and perform my actions but this is only working when removing an account/store, the Stores' count is correctly updated, but not when adding an account/store.
I also tried polling Application.Session.Accounts.Count instead of Application.Session.Stores.Count but it does not work either when an account is added or when it is deleted.
Could anyone provide insights or alternative approaches to reliably detect when new accounts are added in Outlook?

The local variable (stores) goes out of scope and gets released by the Garbage Collector. Make sure your declare the object raising events on the global/class level to make sure it stays alive.

I changed it as you suggested to make it persistent throughout the app life-cycle in the ThisAddin_Startup method but still not working. The event is never fired regardless if I add or remove an account and I subscribe to the event StoreAdd and BeforeStoreRemove respectively. Any ideas? Application.Session.Stores.StoreAdd += Stores_StoreAdd; Application.Session.Folders.FolderAdd += Folders_FolderAdd;

Application.Session.Stores.StoreAdd += Stores_StoreAdd cannot possibly work - this is even worse: instead of a local variable, you now set up the event handler on a temporary variable created by the compiler (Application.Session.Stores) that you cannot possibly reference and store in a global variable.

You need to initialize your new global variable, and then set up the event handler on that variable.

I also did it. I created a global variable in ThisAddin class:
private Outlook.Stores mystores = null;
Then I initialized it within the ThisAddin_Startup method:
mystores= Application.Session.Stores;
mystores.StoreAdd+=Stores_StoreAdd;
and StoreAdd event is not being fired when adding a new Outlook account.

Can you see that event fire in OutlookSpy? Click Namespace button, select Stores, click Browse, go to the Events tab and look at the log at the bottom of the tab

I have installed OutlookSpy but for some reason it is not appearing in Outlook anywhere. I am using office 365 Apps for business.

I see that the StoreAdd event is fired after Outlook starts only. Don't know why it is fired on Outlook starts but not in real time when the account is successfully added, maybe this is the normal functioning of Outlook¿?

Do you see OutlookSpy in File | Options | Addins? Are you using Simplified or Standard ribbon?

I don't see OutlookSpy in File -> Options -> Addins
